Converting SVG's to be rendered with ctx commands in JS
Lets say I have an svg,
<svg viewBox="188.1601 295.929 33.6399 36" width="33.6399" height="36" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
  <path fill="#744EAA" d="M 192.8 299.929 C 195.8 299.929 197.8 301.929 200.8 305.929 C 203.8 309.929 208.757 313.12 212.8 313.929 C 217.8 314.929 221.8 318.929 221.8 324.929 C 221.8 329.826 217.954 331.929 212.8 331.929 C 207.8 331.929 203.8 328.929 198.8 323.929 C 193.8 318.929 188.8 309.929 188.8 305.929 C 188.8 301.929 189.8 299.929 192.8 299.929 Z" transform="matrix(0.9999999999999999, 0, 0, 0.9999999999999999, 0, 0)"/>
  <path fill="#77B255" d="M 190.315 295.929 C 191.563 295.929 191.563 297.177 191.563 298.424 C 191.563 300.188 192.811 299.553 194.059 299.553 C 195.305 299.553 197.8 301.929 197.8 301.929 L 194.058 301.929 C 192.81 301.929 194.058 304.543 192.81 304.543 C 191.562 304.543 191.562 303.355 190.315 303.355 C 189.068 303.355 188.8 306.929 188.8 306.929 C 188.8 306.929 187.196 302.776 189.067 300.905 C 190.315 299.657 187.82 295.929 190.315 295.929 Z" transform="matrix(0.9999999999999999, 0, 0, 0.9999999999999999, 0, 0)"/>
</svg>

and I want to convert it to ctx commands so it can be rendered on a 2D Canvas game. Here is an example of what I have:
// body
    ctx.fillStyle = '#ffe763';
    ctx.strokeStyle = '#a29442';
    ctx.beginPath();
    const pos = offset(this.renderX, this.renderY);
    ctx.arc(pos.x, pos.y, this.r, 0, Math.PI * 2);
    ctx.stroke();
    ctx.fill();
    ctx.closePath();

I tried to find an online converter but they just rendered something at the top left of my screen in low quality.

If you're just looking for a library that does this then you can't ask such questions here. If not, what's the problem with just continuing/expanding on what you've done so far? I.e. where are you stuck?

Please read about Using SVG paths in canvas.

Have a look at path2D()

path2D() is rather laggy, I need to convert svg's to ctx commands which is where I am stuck

"Laggy"? Why would it be? If you only have to deal with bare <path> elements then it's indeed trivial to use Path2D. If it's for any svg, then a lib would be better. But anyhow this quesion is eithet too broad, or implicitely asks for a library.

Because path2d keeps redrawing, and the game is already in ctx

"Because path2d keeps redrawing"? No it doesn't draw anything. It just saves the drawing commands. stroke(path) or fill(path) will draw something, not Path2D(), which in terms of raw performance is just the same as using the context's drawing method, except that you need to do it only once and can cache the object, making it actually faster than using the context commands if drawn multiple times

To implement a full-blow SVG renderer in canvas is quite some work... But if you're in control of the SVG exports you might be able to get away with a very limited implementation like this one:

Use ctx.scale and ctx.translate to implement viewBox. This ensures we can render our canvas at any resolution without having to worry about the unit system of the SVG drawing
Use Path2D to construct a path based on the SVG d attribute

I've put some of the limitations of this approach in comments, but just to be sure I'll list them here as well:

Only loops over path elements. If you need stuff like <circle />, <rect />, etc. you'll have to implement those yourself.
Only accepts fill attributes directly set to path elements.
Skips transform on path (al though this one is not hard to add)

All in all I think I would recommend an approach where you render svg images to image data and put that in your canvas instead...
Using image data


const W = 400;
const H = 400;

const svgString = `<svg viewBox="188.1601 295.929 33.6399 36" width="33.6399" height="36" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
  <path fill="#744EAA" d="M 192.8 299.929 C 195.8 299.929 197.8 301.929 200.8 305.929 C 203.8 309.929 208.757 313.12 212.8 313.929 C 217.8 314.929 221.8 318.929 221.8 324.929 C 221.8 329.826 217.954 331.929 212.8 331.929 C 207.8 331.929 203.8 328.929 198.8 323.929 C 193.8 318.929 188.8 309.929 188.8 305.929 C 188.8 301.929 189.8 299.929 192.8 299.929 Z" transform="matrix(0.9999999999999999, 0, 0, 0.9999999999999999, 0, 0)"/>
  <path fill="#77B255" d="M 190.315 295.929 C 191.563 295.929 191.563 297.177 191.563 298.424 C 191.563 300.188 192.811 299.553 194.059 299.553 C 195.305 299.553 197.8 301.929 197.8 301.929 L 194.058 301.929 C 192.81 301.929 194.058 304.543 192.81 304.543 C 191.562 304.543 191.562 303.355 190.315 303.355 C 189.068 303.355 188.8 306.929 188.8 306.929 C 188.8 306.929 187.196 302.776 189.067 300.905 C 190.315 299.657 187.82 295.929 190.315 295.929 Z" transform="matrix(0.9999999999999999, 0, 0, 0.9999999999999999, 0, 0)"/>
</svg>`;

const img = document.createElement("img");
img.addEventListener("load", e => {
  draw(W, H);
});

img.src = `data:image/svg+xml;utf8,${encodeURIComponent(svgString)}`;
document.body.appendChild(img);

const cvs = document.querySelector("canvas");
const ctx = cvs.getContext("2d");


const draw = (width, height) => {
  cvs.width = width;
  cvs.height = height;
  ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0, width, height);
}
img,
canvas {
  background: #efefef;
}

h2 {
  margin: 0;
}
<h2>Canvas</h2>
<canvas></canvas>
<br/>
<button onclick="draw(100, 100)">100⨯100px</button>
<button onclick="draw(200, 200)">200⨯200px</button>
<button onclick="draw(400, 400)">400⨯400px</button>
<h2>Svg source</h2>



Recreating paths using drawing commands


const W = 400;
const H = 400;

const svg = document.querySelector("svg");
const cvs = document.querySelector("canvas");
const ctx = cvs.getContext("2d");


const draw = (width, height) => {
  // Viewbox
  const { width: vbw, height: vbh, x, y } = svg.viewBox.baseVal;
  cvs.width = width;
  cvs.height = height;

  ctx.scale(width / vbw, height / vbh);
  ctx.translate(-x, -y);


  // Shortcut: only implement <path />
  for (const path of svg.querySelectorAll("path")) {
    // Shortcut: only support direct fill attributes
    // (e.g. no inheritance from parent <g>)
    const fill = path.getAttribute("fill");
    const d = path.getAttribute("d");

      // Shortcut: skip transform attribute
    const p = new Path2D(d);

    ctx.fillStyle = fill;
    ctx.fill(p);
  }
}

draw(W, H);
svg,
canvas {
  background: #efefef;
}

h2 {
  margin: 0;
}
<h2>SVG</h2>
<svg viewBox="188.1601 295.929 33.6399 36" width="33.6399" height="36" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
  <path fill="#744EAA" d="M 192.8 299.929 C 195.8 299.929 197.8 301.929 200.8 305.929 C 203.8 309.929 208.757 313.12 212.8 313.929 C 217.8 314.929 221.8 318.929 221.8 324.929 C 221.8 329.826 217.954 331.929 212.8 331.929 C 207.8 331.929 203.8 328.929 198.8 323.929 C 193.8 318.929 188.8 309.929 188.8 305.929 C 188.8 301.929 189.8 299.929 192.8 299.929 Z" transform="matrix(0.9999999999999999, 0, 0, 0.9999999999999999, 0, 0)"/>
  <path fill="#77B255" d="M 190.315 295.929 C 191.563 295.929 191.563 297.177 191.563 298.424 C 191.563 300.188 192.811 299.553 194.059 299.553 C 195.305 299.553 197.8 301.929 197.8 301.929 L 194.058 301.929 C 192.81 301.929 194.058 304.543 192.81 304.543 C 191.562 304.543 191.562 303.355 190.315 303.355 C 189.068 303.355 188.8 306.929 188.8 306.929 C 188.8 306.929 187.196 302.776 189.067 300.905 C 190.315 299.657 187.82 295.929 190.315 295.929 Z" transform="matrix(0.9999999999999999, 0, 0, 0.9999999999999999, 0, 0)"/>
</svg>

<h2>Canvas</h2>
<canvas></canvas>
<br/>
<button onclick="draw(100, 100)">100⨯100px</button>
<button onclick="draw(200, 200)">200⨯200px</button>
<button onclick="draw(400, 400)">400⨯400px</button>



